# How to block access to a site from IE8 or less?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, user-agent, extjs4.2

i create a javascript webapp based on Extjs 4.2. A lot of feature of this framework doesn't work correctly with IE8 (and i don't know the result with previous versions). I'm searching the more clean way to block the access of my web app using user agent like IE8 or lesser from displaying a message and avoid the login to the webapp.

Anytype of help is usefull

Comment: Use conditional statements to display a warning telling users that the site won't work correctly with that browser, don't block them completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( ! Ext.isIE6 || ! Ext.isIE7 ) {
    yourapp.init();
} else {
    //show the element that directs people to http://browsehappy.com/
}
```

Comment: probably it's the simplest and most effective way to do that. 
Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't block access, I would show a message that says features in this application may not function correctly. Denying access is bad. If you want easy IE8 detection checkout [Conditionizr](http://conditionizr.com) and the [IE8 detect](https://github.com/conditionizr/conditionizr/blob/master/detects/ie8.js) (I created it):

```
/*!
 * IE8
 * @cc_on Conditional Compilation to test the
 * JavaScript versions
 */
conditionizr.add('ie8', [], function () {
  var version = false;
  /*@cc_on if (@_jscript_version > 5.7 && !/^(9|10)/.test(@_jscript_version))
  version = true @*/
  return version;
});
```

This gives you:

```
if (conditionizr.ie8) {
  // stuff for ie8
}

conditionizr.on('ie8', function () {
  // callbacks
});
```

Plus you can load polyfills/other assets. Perhaps you can load Ext.js for non-IE8 so that the app doesn't break, it just doesn't serve instead.

With Conditionizr you can ignore browsers too using `!`:

```
conditionizr.on('!ie8'[, callback]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use one of [IE's conditional statements](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) within your markup:

```
<html>
    ...
    <body>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <p>Notice: As you are using an old browser some features of this
               web app may not work for you. Please update.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Anything contained within the `<!--[if lte IE 8]>` block here targets any version of Internet Explorer less than or equal to IE8.